# How to use Amazon SES Mailbox Simulator

Tags: c#, amazon-ses

i'm using Amazon .net SDK. I understand to send mail with [Simulator mailboxes](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MailboxSimulator.html). But don't understand where to use simulator mail, customer mail in TO, FROM field.

For example: i have `CustomerMail`, `MyVerifiedMail`, `SimulatorMails` including bounce@simulator.amazonses.com, success@simulator.amazonses.com, ooto@simulator.amazonses.com etc...

My code is here

```
SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest()                        
                        .WithDestination(new Destination() { ToAddresses = { CustomerMail } })
                        .WithSource(VerifiedMail)
                        .WithReturnPath(VerifiedMail)
                        .WithMessage(
                            new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Message(new Content("Title"),
                            new Body().WithHtml(new Content("Body"));
```

`WithDestination:` CustomerMail, `WithSource:` VerifiedMail, `WithReturnPath:` SimulatorMail ?

or

`WithDestination:` SimulatorMail, `WithSource:` CustomerMail, `WithReturnPath:` VerifiedMail ?

Please tell me how to use simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Do you read this http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MailboxSimulator.html?

Use MailboxSimulator as usual, only different: you have to use simulator's emails.

In your code:

```
SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest()                        
                    .WithDestination(new Destination() { ToAddresses = { SimulatorMails } })
                    .WithSource(VerifiedMail)
                    .WithReturnPath(VerifiedMail)
                    .WithMessage(
                        new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Message(new Content("Title"),
                        new Body().WithHtml(new Content("Body"));
```

Comment: The docs don't actually say how to find the mailbox simulator.